# Capturing video with cell phone integrated camera via Java ME

Tags: java, video, java-me, mobile-phones, capture

I'm trying to capture a video stream using the video camera on a Java ME capable cell phone. How do I go about doing this? I've read about using MMAPI for capturing still images through a live camera feed, but I'm not sure whether it can capture a video stream that can be saved (with sound) and forwarded to a remote server.

Comment: Unfortunately, once you have chosen a phone, you'll have to experiment to figure out exactly what video encodings it supports. Deploying that kind of application of many different handset models will quickly become very difficult.

Comment: That is not really a problem, though I'll keep that in mind. Even the client deployed by Qik does not support all phones. Hopefully Android devices are better in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a nice writeup on the subject in [this javaworld article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2007/jw-09-mobilevideo1.html).

Hope that helps,
Petri